# CodeDom Add File Properties?

Tags: c#, codedom

Hello Guys I want to know how to add some File Properties (file creation date, description, file version etc...) to the
output of the compiled code.

I already know how to add an Icon :

```
param.CompilerOptions += "/target:winexe" + " " + "/win32icon:" + "\"" + textBox1.Text + "\"";
```

I also read the MSDN documents,but they dont teach/show me how to do this...

Comment: Come on please help me! BUMP

Comment: Do what? You just showed how to add a icon, I don't see what your question is, is it you don't know what to do with `param`? Can you explain more what kind of "properties" you are trying to add?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I want to add properties to the output exe like creation date,description,file version etc.

Comment: Then edit your question and say what properties you want to set, it will help people understand what you want.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain edited. Do you know how to add properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just do it the same way you would do it with a normal complied assembly, just add the [assembly attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w8c1y2s.aspx) in one of the source files that is being complied using codedom to set your properties

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("SampleProject")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Microsoft")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("SampleProject")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © Microsoft 2011")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the file property you are talking about . If you are looking at compiling any code via code take a look at the type **System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters** or if you are looking to compile using 
the csharp compiler csc.exe then take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ds95cz0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx .

Comment: I want to add the creation date,file version,description etc to the output of the compiled source code (.exe)...

Comment: This info should be part of assembly common info.cs in a normal assembly , you can create  this info in any source file and compile the assembly .