# C# Dynamic Assembly with assembly information

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

In my code, I create a DLL dynamically.  The following code is what I use to create my DLL:

```
/// <summary>
/// See CodeDom example hon how its used
/// </summary>
/// <param name="source_code"></param>
/// <param name="assemblies"></param>
/// <param name="generate_executable"></param>
/// <param name="compiler_options"></param>
/// <param name="output"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Tuple<Assembly, string> CompileSource(string source_code, List<string> assemblies, bool generate_executable = false, string compiler_options = "/optimize", string output_assembly = "")
{
    CompilerParameters compilerParams = null;
    CSharpCodeProvider provider = null;
    CompilerResults result = null;
    string errors = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
        foreach (var entry in assemblies)
        {
            compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(entry);
        }
        if (output_assembly != string.Empty)
            compilerParams.OutputAssembly = output_assembly;

        compilerParams.GenerateExecutable = generate_executable;
        compilerParams.GenerateInMemory = false;
        compilerParams.IncludeDebugInformation = true;
        compilerParams.CompilerOptions = compiler_options;

        result = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source_code);

        foreach (CompilerError error in result.Errors)
        {
            errors += String.Format("{0}({1},{2}: error {3}: {4}", error.FileName, error.Line, error.Column, error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
    }

    return Tuple.Create(result.CompiledAssembly, errors);


}
```

What I would like to do is add Assembly Information like the company, product, title, etc.
Looking at this [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio-net-framework) and [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/set-attributes) to add it but I'm not sure how to do it.

[image]

The CompilerParameters doesn't seem to give an option to add these attributes.

Anyone have a suggestion if it can be done on how to add this information?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17112163/8967612

Comment: I saw that but the problem is I pass the code as a string like the following example:

            string code =  @"var date = DateTime.Parse(""1/1/2013 11:54 AM""); " +
                                 @"retVal = date.ToString(""MMMM"") + "" "" + date.ToString(""dd"") + "", "" + date.ToString(""yyyy"");";

Comment: I tried adding @"[assembly: AssemblyCompany(""Pain Company"")]" in the string but it fails

Comment: Make sure you add it at the top of the file and to also call `using System.Reflection;`. Here's a [full example](https://pastebin.com/6sCBZkq6) that works just fine for me using your method above.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, I got it to work.  I appreciate the advice

Comment: *This may help:* > [***https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110250/codedom-add-file-properties***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110250/codedom-add-file-properties) I can not comment yet so i posted this as answer.